# Search Large ConcurrentBag?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, concurrency

.NET 4.5.1

I have a ConcurrentBag with 200,000 objects. An object is considered "unique" by two properties of type long.

I need to check the bag for a previous existence of a unique object, and if it does not exist, add it.

I think doing something like the below is not correct -

```
var foundRef = mybag.Where( r => r.mainid == tempObj.mainid &&
r.subid == tempObj.subid);
```

what is the right way to search the bag as quickly as possible? I do need the concurrency/safety of the 'bag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not to use `ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<long, long>, Foo>`? Your data will be indexed by these two properties `mainid` and `subid`.

The only disadvantage of this approach is that you have to create new `Tuple<long, long>` each time you want to retrieve a value from the dictionary:

```
var foundRef = myDict[new Tuple<long, long>(tempObj.mainid, tempObj.subid)];
```

But it will give you the fastest possible access time close to O(1).